# Is any content in Farming Classic Collection for the PSN cut compared to the PSP version?

Tags: psn, psp, harvest-moon

The text on the store page kinda hints towards hit, roughly translated from my language:

> This Product is a digital version of a Disc-based PSP title. Some
>   functions can be different from the version for psp or are not
>   available.

I ask because I thought about buying the Farming Classic Collection which is not available in Germany and costs about 60€ here. Same with Harvest Moon Boy and Girl. -.-

It is only 15€ for that Collection on PSN.
Does someone own the Collection and can tell me whats different?
It says it has 356 MB for 2 Harvest Moon Games, which seems a bit low to me. My Playstation 1 Version of BTN has about 210 MB for 1 Game.

Comment: It would depend on the game itself.  I don't think we can answer a general case, but if you want to focus just on the PSP Harvest Moon, I think we can answer this.

Comment: Well, I need an answer for Harvest Moon Farming Classic Collection which I am gonna play on a PSP.

Comment: Yeah, but your title implies you're looking for info on every PSP game that's also on the PSN store.

Comment: Well, it does say it on nearly every game for PSP that you can buy on the store. I am hoping that someone actually bought something there and can answer that question.

Comment: That might be a bit broad, as I bet it would depend on the specific game.  I'd really recommend narrowing your focus to just the game you really want to know about.

Comment: I discribed the problem, if nobody wants to help, well fine. Plenty of other sites out there, no problem at all :D

Comment: @leetfan I modified your question (at least the title) to be more specifically about HM Farming Classic Collection. Is this okay?